# Spring boot error : Loading module from “http://localhost:8080/index.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“application/json”)

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot, mustache

**I followed a tutorial, I copied and pasted the code, but it's not working!**

The goal is to use react and spring-boot together to send web pages to the user (I think). So when they go to a api pathway, it should just load up the index.js.

It worked with just basic html, when I tried to follow the part for javascript and react it stopped working.

**What happens:**

when I go to localhost:8080/react (this mapping should load a mustache file, index.js) I just get a blank page, pressing f12 (open browser console) showed me this error:
[image: Loading module from “http://localhost:8080/index.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“application/json”).]

when i click on the link in the image above i get a 404 not found error.

when I go to localhost:8080/ I get the html mustache file as expected.

console:
[image]

**code:**

The tutorial made me locally download node.js, then it made me download plugins (parcel and react-dom), and then gave me 4 small javascript files to make.

Here is the github link (.idea, .mvn, node and node_modules are no there because they are too big
) :

https://github.com/S1coding/halp

File directory:

[image]

Comment: Can you show your Request in React as well as your Controller in Spring Boot? The error suggests, that Spring Boot (at least this endpoint) does not allow JSON Data.

Comment: I can't paste the code here in a formatted way, so I'll just give you a GitHub link that shows everything:
https://github.com/S1coding/halp
Don't worry it's not much, it's just a spring boot init file, except target/static, it was generated by parcel, not sure what it is. Wait let me just give you the tutorial i was following to begin with:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mFsF20TafAyRcOwXZJ7Co6rdCGR7VWHn/view?usp=sharing
So I got no errors from my code on the IDE, but I got errors on the browser. I think i'll just move on from this, there might be some silly error I'll never find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out that the tutorial was just dead wrong.
The way it teaches just doesn't work?
So I didn't do anything wrong, the tutorial was just wrong.